# unit test for custom exception (chained exception python 3)

Tags: python, python-unittest

Working on testing custom based exceptions within python3, within the client code I have:

```
   class myCustomException(Exception):
      pass

   def someFunc():

     try:
       mathCheck = 2/0
       print(mathCheck)
     except ZeroDivisionError as e:
       raise myCustomException from e
```

On the test side:

```
  def testExceptionCase(self):

     with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError) as captureException:
       self.someFunc()
```

My question is:
How to essentially capture the chained exception i.e. the `myCustomException` using unittest (so proving that the custom exception did get called and raised from the base exception which is `ZeroDivisonError`), assume I have already done the import of unittest, and imports within client-test files.

Is there a way to say we were able to keep track of the traceback chaining from `ZeroDivisionError` and `myCustomException`. Basically, this test should also fail if it didn't raise the `myCustomException`. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from client import MyCustomException

def testExceptionCase(self):
    with self.assertRaises(MyCustomException):
        self.someFunc()
```

Also you may want to use UpperCamelCase for Exceptions and Classes in general

Comment: would it be necessary to do a standalone import of the custom exception like how you have it, if I have already imported the client file which has the class setup?

Comment: No in that case you could just use the notation `client.MyCustomException`. I added the import statement to make it explicit  that your test module needs access to `MyCustomException`

Comment: Sounds good. But it doesn't have to be off base type `ZeroDivisonError` in params like you have it, why not `Exception` to handle other possible cases in case it's not derived from `ZeroDivisionError`? The notation you have shown, would it be this then `assertRaises(client.MyCustomException)` or can it still be `assertRaises(MyCustomException)`.

Comment: Since you were raising on `ZeroDivisonError` I automatically assumed you wanted to derive from that type of exception.

Comment: Cool. No need for the notation shown in your comment? It would just be the custom exception being called without having to give full path to it using `client`?

Comment: Yes if you import client in your test module then you can access it via client

Comment: Ok I see, but my question you have this `client.MyCustomException` when `client` is not necessary, it can just be `MyCustomException` especially when `client` is imported at the top of my test file.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the fact that your intention is to derive from `Exception`. However if you want to raise your `CustomException` in many different circumstances, say on `ZeroDivisionError` and `KeyError` then you should probably consider whether it makes sense to have a `CustomException`.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand your last question.

Comment: My question is only to the notation you have, I agree with everything else: `client.MyCustomException` why the need for `client.` before hand when the import for `client` is done at the top already.

Comment: if you only import client in your test module then you won't be able to access your CustomException without using the namespace client. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, I think you will have update the answer to have `import client.MyCustomException` then and remove the `import MyCustomException`.